# my analog microphone does not work

Tags: 9.10, microphone

I am using Ubuntu 9.10 and my analog microphone does not work.

I tried to use ekiga, but my voice is not heard. I used the audio recorder and tryed to record my own voice, but nothing is recorded.

I started gnome-volume-control and disabled mute in the input part, and pushed the amplification to the maximum.

I started alsa info and pasted the output here: http://pastebin.com/ep6gBMre

I tried to use alsmixer in the gnome terminal, but I can't use it because the controls are distorted.

For any advice I would be grateful.

Comment: How do you mean "I tried to use alsmixer in the gnome terminal, but I can't use it because the controls are distorted." In what way is it distorted?  BTW there is a gui alsamixer `gnome-alsamixer`

Comment: My gnome terminal is not displaying it properly. http://i.imgur.com/IMept.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution, but I had to overcome some hurdles, I will keep this here in case some else finds it.

1. alsamixer did not work well in gnome-terminal, it didn't show all available buttons, and was more or less unusable. The solution for this problem was to call xterm from the gnome-terminal, and then start alsamixer in the xterm. xterm worked great for alsa mixer.
2. Somehow, I experimented a lot in alsa mixer. I think that the final solution was to change the capture device from digital to analog microphone. In other words, I changed everything that said "digital" to analog. And somehow at one point, it just started working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you have properly configured your audio input, I suggest you take a look at [Built-in microphone not detected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18547/built-in-microphone-not-detected/45410#45410)  whose answer is placed here for your convenience:

> Take a look at this:
>
> ### [Skype doesn't find my audio input](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31572/skype-doesnt-find-my-audio-input/31663#31663)
>
> Original answer by @Treviño, Posted here for your convenience:
>
> The only way I've found to make my
>   internal mic work in my laptops is to
>   use `pavucontrol` (install it from the
>   homonymous package) and disabling the
>   volume of a channel (the right or the
>   left one), since most of microphones
>   are mono in fact.
>
> This is an huge workaround, by the
>   way. I guess that this annoying bug
>   should be fixed somewhere!

[image: Pavucontrol - Input volume settings]

It worked for me in several laptops with stereo and/or mono built in microphone (on screen or panel).

Additionally, you may wish to take a look at your sound preferences, mentioned in the same page. Click this link: [Skype doesn't find my audio input](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31572/skype-doesnt-find-my-audio-input/31577#31577) (this will lead you to a different answer in the same page).

Also posted here for your convenience:

> Under Sound Preferences, please post
>   the "Hardware Tab" in order to check
>   your profile, which should use at
>   least an output + an input being in
>   use. Otherwise, your hardware is not
>   using the input profile which can be
>   chosen right there.
>
> This answer may be changed after your
>   posting in order to give you further
>   details. Here is a sample. Thank you.

[image]

> Edit
>   -- Here is the [conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/skype-fixing) in the general chat room.

Good luck!

Comment: I changed the Sound preferences in the hardware tab from analog stereo duplex to analog surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input. And tested it, unfortunately, the problem is still there. I read the conversation in the general chat room, if I understand it correctly, it basically is talking about the same thing. I will try pavucontrol next and gnome-alsamixer.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following steps:

1. Run alsamixer
2. Unmute all the outputs by hitting <kbd>M</kbd>
3. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go the capture settings
4. Highlight the “Mic” setting using the arrow keys.
5. Hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to enable the microphone.
6. Highlight the “Capture” setting using the arrow keys.
7. Hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to enable capture (note that just because you have volume
   bar here doesn’t mean it is enabled).
8. Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>.