# No Microphone picked up on Ubuntu 16.04 on Macbook Pro

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, macbook, microphone

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Macbook Pro. Everything is going great but my internal microphone nor headphones with microphone are being picked up.

I have tried: checking the hardware works on another OS, Alsamixer, PAVU (Pulsa Audio Volume Control all to no avail.

All of these show an internal microphone etc. but dont pick up anything. Is there a driver I need to install perhaps?

Here is this that may help?

```
 $ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xa0610000 irq 37
```

Mainly trying to use in Skype and Discord but don't think that makes a difference

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by

Adding the following line to the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf: `options snd-hda-intel model=mbp101`

Comment: can you please explain what is `mbp101` and where did you get it?

Comment: @SadeghAlirezaie Actually, how he got lucky is Mac was a 10,1 or he followed the step of the Doug answer. For me, the answer is mbp81 because my Mac is a version 8,1, Look under your Mac, you will see a number starting with a, such as a1278, then search here: https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with my Macbook air running KDE Neon (ubuntu 18).

Here is what fixed my issue:

#### 1. Added the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mba6
```

To find the model I first ran:

```bsh
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
```

Then searched [HD-Audio Codec-Specific Models](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html) to find the corresponding model.

#### 2. Changed my sound card profile from `Analogue Stereo Output` to `Analogue Stereo Duplex`

Check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPZJa.png) for an image (I don't have enough reputation)

I also disabled my HDMI sound (top device in picture), though I don't believe this had any effect

#### 3. Reboot!

This worked for me, hopefully this is useful to somebody else.

Based on helpful answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129305) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/27814)

Answer (score 0):

audio capture muted when first installed is good for not having feedback

```
alsamixer -c 0 --view capture
```

use arrow keys and spacebar to select capture and set level.

check for similar changes in Pulseaudio:

```
pavucontrol -t 3
```

to make sure settings are saved:

```
sudo alsactl store
```

configuration file usually saved to /etc/asound.state

current skype versions have playback and recording via Pulseaudio if left on "Default"

pavucontrol Playback tab should show skype stream for caller and another for sound effects, my system shows that stream with chromium icon.

Comment: hey nik, thanks for trying but i still didnt have luck, does this look correct?

https://imgur.com/a/gbl9q

seems like i would want something to show for internal mic?

Comment: agree - would expect to see level control there. 
and looks like from solution comment you have it sorted out now

Answer (score 0):

I did those steps, but under Input Device I still have a Line In (unplugged) while under Output Device it recognize my headset is plugged in.

[image]