# Macbook with Ubuntu - Headphone microphone not working (but built-in microphone works fine)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

I'm new in the Linux world. So I've installed Ubuntu 20.4 on my Macbook Air 2014...
Everything works fine, audio, microphone, however, my problem arises when I try to plug in the headphone. The audio works fine, but I can't seen to make the headset mic to work.

I did some research, found this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984239/no-microphone-picked-up-on-ubuntu-16-04-on-macbook-pro?newreg=4db599f6c0dc4f09acfce1e4a7d85f17)

Did all the workarounds... I've looked up on the kernel website to see which codec my computer uses:

**Cirrus Logic CS4208
mba6
MacBook Air 6,1 and 6,2**

Then I've openned Visual Studio and added the line bellow at the bottom of **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mba6
```

After reboot, nothing has changed. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: There is a very old bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1410618
It may help if you mark the bug as affecting you?

Answer (score 2):

Ok folks I managed to solve the issue:

First check without unplugging the cable the result of:

```
sudo hdajacksensetest -a
```

Then connect the cable and run it again:

```
sudo hdajacksensetest -a
```

There should be some difference, with now some pin marked as `"(Not connected): present = Yes"` which initially (without the cable) showed `"(Not connected): present = No"`. If this is not the case your cable is not being detected and you may have another issue.

Then run:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
```

And make sure it is `Cirrus Logic CS4208`
, if that is the case, search the particular model of your computer here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html (in the CS4208 section if that is your case) find the code of your computer: `mbp55` or `imac27` or `imac27_122` and then edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Erase every line in there and write (supposing your model was `mbp55`):

```
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp55
```

Then restart the computer and it should work
(Solution by Doug White)