# Microphone is nor recognized on macbook pro 11,3 running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, microphone, macbook, macbook-pro, headset

I'm using an Apple headset on my macbook pro 11,3 running Ubuntu 20.04.
The same headset is running properly on osx: when I insert the jack the microphone on the headset is recognized and start working, but Ubuntu doesn't recognized it at all.

I tried with hdajackretask and following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984239/no-microphone-picked-up-on-ubuntu-16-04-on-macbook-pro) instructions but it didn't resolve.

The audio chip seem to be:  Cirrus Logic CS4208

Can you please help me? Thanks